# How do I deploy an Angular project on netlify?

Tags: angular, deployment, build, netlify

I previously had this Angular project on digital ocean but want to move it to netlify. I deployed a React project without backend using npm build but not sure how to do it for angular with a back end.

I read I should use ng build but the error I get is "The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

My github to this project is https://github.com/davyoon/vitalNote.  Please help.  I've been stuck on this for a while.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried going through any of the online guides?
E.g: https://itnext.io/deploy-your-angular-app-to-netlify-in-minutes-b994868e297f

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are running the command in the application root folder. if not move to root folder and run the build command.

And if you're already at root folder and still getting the same issue, try following command.

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=<Your current version>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  hmm I tried that and i got the error message "Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating." so i committed and tried again.  Then I got the messages "Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 14 dependencies.
Package is not installed."
Any idea what might be the problem?